# Как сделать ввод данных в pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, telebot

Нужно что бы функция продолжила выполнение, только при условии того, что пользователь отправил сообщение.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: вам надо просто получить сообщение?

Comment: Я ввожу команду и ожидаю ещё одного сообщения с необходимым текстом. Пока второе не отправится, код не должен воспроизводится, а как бы стоять на паузе.

Comment: Присылать подтверждение отправки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)
car_list = ['toyota', 'mazda']
#Список возможных машин

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

def answer(message):
    if message.text == '/start':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите марку машины:')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я вас не понимаю')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
    if message.text in car_list:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Информация о вашей машине:...')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Укажите модель машины , а не вашего НЛО')
```

Comment: Вы меня, вероятно, не так поняли. Мне нужно что бы когда бот принимал команду, к примеру /start, я должен был ввести какое либо сообщение, что бы код в команде /start взаимодействовал с ним.

Comment: @xkrystall , а вы пробовали await?

Comment: Я незнаю о такой функции. И нет, ваш код выше не решает проблему. Я попытаюсь сейчас разъяснить максимально понятно. Пользователь вводит команду /start => вводит какое либо слово, которое я незнаю, марку машины к примеру => ему выводится указанная информация по этому слову.

Comment: @xkrystalll попробуйте сейчас

Answer (score 1):

Может вы и решили проблему, но попробую помочь.
Вкратце, у бота есть функция `bot.register_next_step_handler()` которая используется для построения цепей.
Разработчик включил в список этот пример https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py

Оставлю пример как в вашем случае.

```
def answer(message):
    if message.text == '/start':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите марку машины:')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, car_name)

def car_name(message):
    text = message.text
    if text == "lada":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Неплохой выбор)")
```